# Rails: suppress missing image routing errors in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

My application loads a lot of images, which in development isn't really necessary, so I don't have the images locally. But, because of that, I get a bunch of routing errors like so:

[image: log]

Can I suppress log messages like this somehow? Gems like [quiet_assets](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) doesn't work because it's a `RoutingError`.

Comment: Do you mean like `unless Rails.env.development?`?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm asking more about what `config` setting will suppress `RoutingErrors` (preferably only if they concern files in `/system/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a catch-all route which suppresses the error:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  get "/system/covers/*covers", to: "application#noop"
end

class ApplicationController
  def noop
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

You could also have it render a default image so that you don't get errors in the browser console.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, and I would totally never have thought of that. Thanks!